# Weird bug when solving LeetCode 117

Tags: java, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem [117. Populating Next Right Pointers in Each Node II](https://leetcode.com/problems/populating-next-right-pointers-in-each-node-ii/description/):

> Given a binary tree
>
> ```
> struct Node {
>   int val;
>   Node *left;
>   Node *right;
>   Node *next;
> }
> ```
>
> Populate each next pointer to point to its next right node. If there is no next right node, the next pointer should be set to `NULL`.
>
> Initially, all next pointers are set to `NULL`.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> [image]

I implemented a simple BFS, but it fails the first test case. What's pretty weird is that, according to my output, at the end of the third iteration of the `while` loop the queue size is 0, but when it checks the queue for the forth iteration's condition, it magically changed to 1!!!

I'm so confused by this behavior.

```java
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
    public int val;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node next;

    public Node() {}
    
    public Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
    }

    public Node(int _val, Node _left, Node _right, Node _next) {
        val = _val;
        left = _left;
        right = _right;
        next = _next;
    }
};
*/

class Solution {
    public Node connect(Node root) {
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.offer(root);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            int size = queue.size();
            System.out.println("-");
            System.out.printf("size: %d%n",  queue.size());
            for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
                Node curr = queue.poll();
                System.out.println("poll");
                curr.next = queue.peek();
                if(curr.left != null){
                    System.out.println(curr.left.val);
                    queue.offer(curr.left);
                } 
                if(curr.right != null){
                    System.out.println(curr.right.val);
                    queue.offer(curr.right);
                } 
            }
            Node last = queue.poll();System.out.println("poll");
            // System.out.println(last.val);
            last.next = null;
            System.out.printf("size: %d%n",  queue.size());
            if(last.left != null){
                System.out.println(last.left.val);
                queue.offer(last.left);
            } 
            System.out.printf("size: %d%n",  queue.size());
            if(last.right != null){
                System.out.println(last.right.val);
                queue.offer(last.right);
            } 
            System.out.printf("size: %d%n",  queue.size());
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

Output generated:

```
-
size: 1
poll
size: 0
2
size: 1
3
size: 2
-
size: 2
poll
4
5
poll
size: 2
size: 2
7
size: 3
-
size: 3
poll
poll
poll
size: 0
size: 0
size: 0
-
size: 1
poll
```

Comment: Doesn't the queue violate the condition that one can only use constant extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when it checks the queue for the forth iteration's condition, it magically changed to 1!!!

The output of LeetCode is misleading you into thinking that output belongs to the same test case. It is not. That 1 comes from running a **second** test case.

And it is with that test case that your code has an issue. The test provides an empty tree to your function, i.e. `root` is `null`. Your code will put that `null` on the queue (and you output the 1), but then when this "node" is pulled from the queue, the reference to its `next` property triggers an exception.

The fix is of course simple...

> Add a `null` check at the top of your function.